# MySql: Select Distinct for words in different order

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have problem with creating query, which getting no duplicate values form my table. Unfortunately, *Full Name* column has Name and Surname in different order.

For example:

```
+----+----------------------+
| ID | Full Name            |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | Marshall Wilson      |
| 2  | Wilson Marshall      |
| 3  | Lori Hill            |
| 4  | Hill Lori            |
| 5  | Casey Dean Davidson  |
| 6  | Davidson Casey Dean  |
+----+----------------------+
```

I would like to get that result:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| ID | Full Name             |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | Marshall Wilson       |
| 3  | Lori Hill             |
| 5  | Casey Dean Davidson   |
+----+-----------------------+
```

My target is to create query, which getting in similar way, for example: *select distinct* for Name and Surname in the same order.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why `Casey Dean Davidson` changed to `Casey Davidson` ?

Comment: Thanks, It was my mistake ;)

Comment: how do you assure that which one in the correct one. I mean `Marshall Wilson` OR `Wilson Marshall`?

Comment: @FatemehNB any one of the two is correct. We just want that both are not returned

Comment: @fioljnw You can split the column into first name and last name and join the split table to itself to see if any name repeats. Then remove those ids from your original table.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 3 substrings in the name ?

Comment: it does not matter which is correct. I do not have to detect what is name or surname. if I find duplicate results then I can take first result.

Comment: @Sahil Dhoked, thanks but I do not think it's optimal solution.

Comment: what is the maximum number of substrings in the name?

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya, rarely but it is possible.

Comment: @FatemehNB, it is not defined but it can be 3

Comment: @fioljnw can you provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ? It is doable but requires some testing.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qg1jVT23JSmfURjReWL1sn/0

Comment: @fioljnw What if a row does not have a duplicate row? it should be in the results too? or the results should only show the rows that has a duplicate row(s)?

Comment: @Sami, If row doesn't have duplicate rows then it should be shown. Each row (let's say unique) should be shown, even if there is no duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires lots of [String operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html), and usage of multiple [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). It *may not be efficient*.

We first *tokenize* the `FullName` into multiple words it is made out of. For that we use a number generator table `gen`. In this case, I have assumed that maximum number of substrings is 3. You can easily extend it further by adding more Selects, like, `SELECT 4 UNION ALL ..` and so on.

We use [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) with [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) function to get a substring out, using a single space character (`' '`) as Delimiter. [`Trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) is used to remove any leading/trailing spaces left.

Now, the trick is to use this result-set as a Derived table, and do a [`Group_Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on the words such that they are sorted in a ascending order. This way even the duplicate names (but substrings in different order),  will get similar `words_sorted` value. Eventually, we simply need to `Group By` on `words_sorted` to weed out the duplicates.

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  MIN(dt2.ID) AS ID, 
  MIN(dt2.FullName) AS FullName 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  dt1.ID, 
  dt1.FullName, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(word = '', NULL, word) ORDER BY word ASC) words_sorted 
FROM 
(
SELECT e.ID, 
       e.FullName, 
       TRIM(REPLACE(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.FullName, ' ', gen.idx), 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.FullName, ' ', gen.idx-1),
         '')) AS word 
FROM employees AS e
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS idx UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 3) AS gen -- You can add more numbers if more than 3 substrings
) AS dt1 
GROUP BY dt1.ID, dt1.FullName
) AS dt2
GROUP BY dt2.words_sorted
ORDER BY ID;

| ID  | FullName            |
| --- | ------------------- |
| 1   | Marshall Wilson     |
| 3   | Hill Lori           |
| 5   | Casey Dean Davidson |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qg1jVT23JSmfURjReWL1sn/1)

Comment: Thank you so so much. I see how much work you put into it but I'm afraid that query can be too heavy for larger base.

Comment: @fioljnw yeah I know about the performance part. But unfortunately in your case, I feel that this is one of the *few possible* solutions, using MySQL. You may also explore Full Text Searching or use specialized databases for this kind of fuzzy searching like Apache SOLR etc

Comment: you give me great idea. I add new column with sorted substring in full name. In simpler and faster way, I would get unique values. Thank you!